# Calculate the average and sum value per minute for each device with DolphinDB SQL statements

Tags: dolphindb

Within a given time range, each section is obtained at every minute. I’d like to calculate the average value for each device per minute and then sum up the three values.

It is expected to return two columns, time and the sum of mean values for the three devices in one minute.

Can I obtain the result with DolphinDB SQL statements?

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to the following DolphinDB SQL statements

```
ids = ["024bafec-0adc-4e51-bffe-793085c0559e", "018b8110-ca1b-4f1e-97b2-0363c8ed49ae", "0164480b-11a8-4312-91e0-c96f9faac95c"]
timePeriod = 2021.01.01T00:00:00.000 : 2021.01.01T00:10:00.000
result = select rowSum(ffill(avg(v))) from loadTable("dfs://GZB_TSDB", "data") where id in ids, time between timePeriod pivot by bar(time, 60000) as minute, id
select sum(rowSum) as v from result group by interval(minute, 1m, "prev") as minute
```